# upgraded to android studio 0.27 and cant build apk to phone

Tags: android, android-studio, apk

I am trying to build and run my android apk on my plugged in phone. When I try I get this error:

```
Waiting for device.
Target device: HT359W907227
Uploading file
    local path: /Users/Mike/Documents/beerPortfolio/BeerPortfolioPro/build/classes/debug/BeerPortfolioPro.apk
    remote path: /data/local/tmp/com.beerportfolio.beerportfoliopro
Local path doesn't exist.
```

I then tried to just build a signed apk and was planning on putting it on my phone myself, but get this error:

```
Error: /Users/Mike/Documents/beerPortfolio/BeerPortfolioPro/build/classes/debug/BeerPortfolioPro.apk (No such file or directory)
```

and

```
Error: 
Unable to open '/private/var/folders/g8/rgjwwnkd5616bcm00tfqgn180000gn/T/android2490128145650687419.apk' as zip archive
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mike I had the same issue when i try to build with eclipse. All I done to solve this problem is by just clean the project and built it again it works.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem when I was developing an application on two different computers.

Because of copying files between those computers, the path for saving the APK was set to the path from the other computer. When I set the correct path on the computer where I'm coding, it worked.

So, make sure you have set a valid path to save your APK.